# Target JRE for Blackberry market

Tags: blackberry, java

What should be the target JRE to cater to the most of the blackberry market?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get useful information from http://us.blackberry.com/developers/choosingtargetos.jsp.

BlackBerry Subscribers by OS:

[image: BlackBerry Subscribers by OS]

App Downloads by OS:

[image: Downloads by OS]